# v-for without using html element in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am a newbie to Vue.js

I am preparing a demo for input elements practices, here is my code.

**HTML**

```html
<div id="inputDiv">
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" v-model="first_name">
    <input type="text" v-model="last_name">
    <input type="email" v-model="email">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" :name="gender" v-model="gender" value="male">Male
      <input type="radio" :name="gender" v-model="gender" value="female">Female
    </div>
    <textarea v-model="address" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <br>
    <div v-for="hobby in hobbies">
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="userHobbies" v-bind:value="hobby">{{hobby}}
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Script**

```js
const inputApp = new Vue({
  el: '#inputDiv',
  data: {
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    email: '',
    gender: 'male',
    address: '',
    userHobbies:[],
    hobbies: ['Reading', 'Cricket', 'Cycling', 'Hiking']
  }
})
```

Here you can see, to display Hobby with label I have to iterate with parent ,

adding a div is not something I want, If I will `v-for` in input element like:

```html
<input 
  type="checkbox" 
  v-for="hobby in hobbies" 
  v-model="userHobbies" 
  v-bind:value="hobby"
>{{hobby}}
```

then it's throwing exception **[Vue warn]: Property or method "hobby" is not defined on the instance**

My question is there any alternative for **v-for** over object elements without using HTML element?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Wrap it in a `template` tag as the template tag will not appear in the final rendered HTML:

```xml
<template v-for="hobby in hobbies">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="userHobbies" v-bind:value="hobby">{{hobby}}
</template>
```

Or even better, improve your markup semantics and use a label tag:

```xml
<label v-for="hobby in hobbies">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="userHobbies" v-bind:value="hobby"> {{hobby}}
</label>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can add template inside of div as template is not rendered to the DOM:

```
  <div id="inputDiv">
    <form action>
      <input type="text" v-model="first_name">
      <input type="text" v-model="last_name">
      <input type="email" v-model="email">
      <div>
        <input type="radio" :name="gender" v-model="gender" value="male">Male
        <input type="radio" :name="gender" v-model="gender" value="female">Female
      </div>
      <textarea v-model="address" id cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      <br>
      <template v-for="hobby in hobbies">
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="userHobbies" v-bind:value="hobby">
        {{hobby}}
      </template>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that, the string interpolation `{{hobby}}` after the  tag is outside the loop, which is why the error is shown, in this specific case, you **have** to wrap it inside something.

If you don't want to specifically use div you can go for label instead which is much more natural in this scenario and now if the user clicks on the label, the checkbox will automatically get selected.

```
<label v-for="hobby in hobbies">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="userHobbies" v-bind:value="hobby"> {{hobby}} <br>
</label>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#inputDiv',
  data: {
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    email: '',
    gender: 'male',
    address: '',
    userHobbies:[],
    hobbies: ['Reading', 'Cricket', 'Cycling', 'Hiking']
  }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="inputDiv">
<form action="">
    <input type="text" v-model="first_name">
    <input type="text" v-model="last_name">
    <input type="email" v-model="email">
    <div>
        <input type="radio" :name="gender" v-model="gender" value="male">Male
        <input type="radio" :name="gender" v-model="gender" value="female">Female
    </div>
    <textarea v-model="address" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <br>
    <label v-for="hobby in hobbies">
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="userHobbies" v-bind:value="hobby">{{hobby}}
        <br>
    </label>
</form>
{{ userHobbies | json }}
</div>
```