# Make a table layout with CSS grid with nested vue v-for loops

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, css-grid

I've nested data I'd like to display in tabular format. Here is some example data; in the real application there may sometimes be dozens of entries in `rows`.

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Example',

  data () {
    return {
      results: [
        { a: 'AAA', rows: { BBB: 'CCC' } },
        { a: 'D', rows: { E: 'F', G: 'H' } },
        { a: 'Tom, Dick & Harry', rows: { x: 'y' } },
      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Note: the inner value ('CCC', 'F', 'H', 'y') might end up being a further nested array or object.

I tried this grid layout, with `v-for` loops:

```
<template>
<div style="width:100%">
  <div v-for="(res,key) in results" :key="key" class="results">
    <div class="A">{{res.a}}</div>
    <div v-for="(c,b) in res.rows" :key="b">
      <div class="B">{{b}}</div>
      <div class="C">{{c}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
<style scoped>
.results {display:grid;grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;}
.A {font-weight:bold;grid-column:1/3;}
.B {grid-column:1;padding:0.5rem;}
.C {grid-column:2;padding:0.5rem;}
</style>
```

(Aside: the more logical `grid-column:1/2`, to get a span of two columns, seems to do nothing...)

This gives me the wrong layout; I've appended a good old-fashioned table layout to show what I am trying to achieve (HTML for that at end of question).

[image: incorrect grid, followed by desired table layout]

Do I have a simple bug? Or, is there a whole better approach to using vue and grid together? (Bearing in mind, as mentioned above, that I may end up with a 3rd v-for loop.)

By the way, last time I tried using grid I gave up, and used `<table>` tags; I got around the problem of `v-for` creating html tags by putting it on a `<tbody>`, i.e. having a table body for each section. But that won't scale to a 3rd v-for loop. And I'd rather use CSS grid, if I can, as it gives more power for responsive layouts.

The table HTML, for reference:

```
  <table border="1" cellspacing=0 style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><b>AAA</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>BBB</td>
      <td>CCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><b>D</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>E</td>
      <td>F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>G</td>
      <td>H</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><b>Tom, Dick & Harry</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>y</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just [stumbled upon the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55865731/841830) of how to deal with vue v-for loops, when you don't want them to create DOM elements, which was exactly what I needed here.

First to explain the problem, and why I got the wrong layout: CSS grids *insist* on [applying the layout to the grid container's child elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout#the_grid_container). (As far as I can tell it is completely inflexible on this, e.g. offering no way to tag a div as not being part of the layout.)

Anyway, the solution was to switch my inner `<div v-for="">` into a `<template v-for="">`

```
<template>
<div style="width:100%">
  <div v-for="(res,key) in results" :key="key" class="results">
    <div class="A">{{res.a}}</div>
    <template v-for="(c,b) in res.rows">
      <div class="B" :key="b">{{b}}</div>
      <div class="C" :key="'_'+b">{{c}}</div>
    </template>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

There is one downside: you cannot put the `:key` on the `<template>` tag. Fair enough, given that it does not get rendered. But that means *every* child element of the `<template>` needs a `:key`, and they each have to be different. I have used a hacky kind of workaround above. (See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/67784407/841830 )

In my actual application, I have dropped those two `:key` definitions, and used `<!-- eslint-disable vue/require-v-for-key -->` to stop eslint complaining. It is [my understanding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) this won't cause any problems as the whole of `res` will be replaced if it changes. But if not sure, go with using `:key` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try with arrays instead objects:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data () {
    return {
      results: [
        { a: 'AAA', rows: [{id:'BBB'}, {id:'CCC', more: [{id: '1'}, {id: '2'}]}] },
        { a: 'D', rows: [{id:'E'}, {id:'F', more: [{id: '1'}, {id: '2'}]}, {id:'G'}, {id:'H', more: [{id: '1'}, {id: '2'}]}] },
        { a: 'Tom, Dick & Harry', rows: [{id:'x'}, {id:'y', more: [{id: '1'}, {id: '2'}]}] },
      ],
    }
  },
})


Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```css
.results {display:grid;grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;}
.A {font-weight:bold;grid-column:1/3;}
.B {grid-column:1;padding:0.5rem;}
.C {grid-column:2;padding:0.5rem;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">

<div style="width:100%">
  <div v-for="(res,key) in results" :key="key" class="results">
    <div class="A">{{res.a}}</div>
    <div v-for="(c,b) in res.rows" :key="b">
      <div class="B">{{c.id}}</div>
      <div v-for="(z,i) in c.more" :key="i">
        <div class="C">{{z.id}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
      
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. This doesn't look like it scales to the 3rd nested loop (unless you are suggesting unrolling all nested objects into a single array?). But I'm more interested in *why* using the array sends the cells horizontally, whereas using the object sends the cells vertically. Can you explain it?

Comment: Hey mate, if you want more nested loops just put more `v-for` loops. In your example you have have 2 divs in nested v-for but in cases `b:c and x:y` only one object.

Comment: I updated answer with more nested objects (if that's what you want to accomplish), take a look pls, cheers :)