# Looping within a select tag with a parent element in VueJS

Tags: vuejs2, ebay-api

I am trying to loop through these categories from eBay and they have a parent category and then children category, but the parent category needs to be able to be selectable. That means I cant use optgroup so I attempted this way with a div tag and was going to add classes to style the parent category differently but the options do not appear in the UI. Is there any kind of parent element I can use here or does anyone have any suggestions of alternative solutions?

```
<div class="rr-field" v-if="ebay.categories">
        <label class="rr-field__label">eBay Category</label>
        <select class="rr-field__input" v-model="marketplaces.ebay.category">
          <option :value="null">Select one..</option>
          <div 
            v-for="(c, index) in ebay.categories"
            :key="index"
          >
            <option :value="c.category.categoryId">
              {{ c.category.categoryName }}
            </option>
            <option
              v-for="(c, index) in c.categoryTreeNodeAncestors"
              :key="index"
              :value="c.categoryId"
              >{{ c.categoryName }}</option
            >
          </div>
        </select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [v-for without using html element in vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55865058/v-for-without-using-html-element-in-vue-js)

Comment: a.) If you are using an UI Framewok like ant or bootstap have a look in docs for a proper select component. b.) Use optgroup and add the parent again as first option. c.) Use option with styling, see answer [Selectable <optgroup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9892421/5025024).